# Changing timesheet punch in and out query to a crosstab query

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to create a crosstab query for a timeclock website I've made. Currently I'm just displaying the result in a table with each day as it's own line.

This is an example of the data.

```
id    type  user    time
4941  1     user1   2017-10-03 11:24:00
4954  2     user1   2017-10-03 14:43:00
4955  1     user1   2017-10-03 14:43:00
4967  2     user1   2017-10-03 16:00:00
```

And here is the query that calculates the data for the current week.

```
SELECT user as UserName, CONVERT (varchar(10), time, 101) AS Date, 
SUM(
    CASE WHEN type = 1 
        THEN - 1 * (datepart(hh , [time]) + datepart(mi , [time]) / 60.0) 
    ELSE datepart(hh , [time]) + datepart(mi , [time]) / 60.0 END) AS Total 
    FROM table WHERE (username LIKE 'user1') 
    and datepart(wk, [time]) = datepart(wk, GETDATE())  
    GROUP BY user, CONVERT (varchar(10), time, 101) ORDER BY Date DESC
```

This displays data just like I wanted.

```
UserName Date          Total
user1    08/21/2019    4.316667
user1    08/20/2019    9.366666
user1    08/19/2019    8.283333
```

However now I want to take that data and put it into a crosstab query so I can show the weeks on each row with the daily data in columns on that row. So far I've tried using a pivot to accomplish this.

```
SELECT  Year, Month, Week,  Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday 
FROM (SELECT  DATENAME(WEEKDAY,  CONVERT (varchar(10), time, 101)) DAY, DATEPART(wk, CONVERT (varchar(10), _time, 101)) as Week
, DATEPART(M, CONVERT (varchar(10), time, 101)) as Month, DATEPART(YYYY, CONVERT (varchar(10), time, 101)) as Year
, SUM(
    CASE 
        WHEN type = 1 
        THEN - 1 * (datepart(hh , [time]) + datepart(mi , [time]) / 60.0) 
    ELSE datepart(hh , [time]) + datepart(mi , [time]) / 60.0 
    END) AS Total 

    FROM table WHERE (username LIKE 'user1') 

    GROUP BY  CONVERT(varchar(10), time, 101) ) p       

PIVOT (SUM(Total)
    FOR DAY IN (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday) ) pvt

ORDER BY Year, Month, Week DESC
```

And I have some success. The data seems to be displaying correctly. However when I try to **ORDER BY** more than one variable the display order is out of whack.

```
Year    Month   Week    Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday  Saturday    Sunday
2017    10  40  NULL    4.600000    0.000000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2018    3   11  0.966667    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5.150000
2019    7   31  NULL    NULL    8.116667    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2019    8   34  8.283333    9.366666    -7.483333   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2019    8   33  8.166667    8.266667    8.083333    8.616668    8.883334    NULL    NULL
2019    8   32  8.350000    8.333333    8.466666    7.883333    7.516666    NULL    NULL
2019    8   31  NULL    NULL    NULL    8.833334    8.000001    NULL    NULL
```

It should be sorting by Year, Week and Month. When I do just the year it works orders fine. But If I add in Week and Month it jumbles up the data in the wrong order. What am I doing wrong? It should look like this.

```
    Year    Week    Month   Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday  Saturday    Sunday
2019    34  8   8.283333    9.366666    -7.483333   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2019    33  8   8.166667    8.266667    8.083333    8.616668    8.883334    NULL    NULL
2019    32  8   8.350000    8.333333    8.466666    7.883333    7.516666    NULL    NULL
2019    31  8   NULL    NULL    NULL    8.833334    8.000001    NULL    NULL
2019    31  7   NULL    NULL    8.116667    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2018    11  3   0.966667    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5.150000
2017    40  10  NULL    4.600000    0.000000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Also, how can I sum the week value to a totals column?